# Conversion Error , There is nothing to process in ssma, while converting from access to sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am getting an error frequently while converting access database to sql which is given below as

```
Conversion Error , There is nothing to process in ssma while converting from access to sql
```

If anyone has faced same problem

please share the answer

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://gaurangpatel.net/access-to-sql-server-migration-and-compatibility-issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got the answer here it is..

According to the log, in your start menu you should have two shortcuts, one to 32-bit version, another to 64-bit. Or you can go to the folder where ssma is installed (again by looking at the shortcut), and see if there are two similar executables. Try both.

link-http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS-SQL-Server/Q_28433397.html

Comment: This solved it for me too. Who knew Access was running on x86...

Answer (score 0):

After hours, I realized that the access file corrupts after a few tries. When i could, I took the original access file and made the complete convertion.